# git alias not accepting shell command, Does it have any solution?

Tags: git, git-alias

Working alias for ref:

```
git config  --global alias.br "branch -vva"
```

The below alias not working

```
git config  --global alias.br "branch -vva  | awk '{print $1}'"
```

The Git alias is not working after adding awk in command. Does it have any fix for it?

Running alias as below in terminal:

```
git br
```

Comment: Without the conventional `!` shell escape there's no shell, alias processing is just argument list substitution. You want `'!git branch -vva | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: See the end of; https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+alias+pipe

Comment: I wouldn't call `!` "conventional" here. You don't have a choice in which prefix to use to indicate  a shell command.

Comment: @jthill tried that too, but getting below error
"expansion of alias 'br' failed; 'git' is not a git command"

Comment: @chepner , thanks for the response, I just confirming it

Comment: @chepner mmm, I can make sense of what you're saying but `!` is what everyone uses for shell escapes is the conventional use I was referring to. "Standard-practice" perhaps?

Comment: There's a typo in my comment there should be no leading singlequote. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @jthill "Standard practice" still implies you have a choice, but (most) everyone agrees to choose `!`. There is no choice here: `git` *mandates* that `!` be used to introduce a shell command to use as the alias. It's not a mere convention (like, for example, the use of `self` as the name of the first parameter in a Python method definition).

Comment: Yes, but Git had a choice. They chose to follow the convention.